# Which Part of JqueryUI contains code for animating colour?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to download only the colour animation part of [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.1&components=1111000000000000000011111111111111), or whatever section it's in, but I can't seem to find out which part it is in. I'm pretty sure it's in "Effects" but do I need more than effects core?

Also can someone confirm whether or not I need to have the JqueryUI core itself as well to get colour animation to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this functionality as a separate plugin without jQueryUI: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: You said you wanted ONLY the color animation part. That's what this is.

Comment: surely this is a separate plugin

Comment: Yes. It is. I'm confused as to why this isn't what you apparently wanted. Please take a minute to read the documentation page before refusing to use it.

Comment: i want the animate colour part of jqueryUI, not color animation plugin. I do know they do essentially the same thing

Comment: They ARE the same thing. Both are official jQuery code. If you want jQueryUI instead, download jQueryUI instead.

Comment: i thought you said it was a separate plugin ( ie not the exact same thing )

Comment: ... actually though, I'm working with wordpress and I've just discovered that it already includes jqueryUI ... so it will be jqueryUI anyway I suppose, but thanks for the info.